# Trying to bring Android Studio project to new computer

Tags: android

I just got a new computer and copied my android studio project folder to my new computer.  When I try to load it I get a error from

> Gradle Sync
>
> Failed to find target android -21
>
> install missing platforms and sync project

I looked to see if there was a option to change the target api, but could not find any options for that.

Comment: Is not the target API. The problem is that in the new computer you dont have installed the Build Tools. When you compile the project then Android Studio detects this problem and prompts you to download the missing ones.

Comment: Check your build.gradle file. You will get to change the Android target. In sdk manager you can update your target android. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just open Android API manager and install missing platform, or - change version defined ion your build.gradle